# equivalent for hadoop fair scheduler in non hadoop application

Tags: java, hadoop

I need the functionality of the hadoop [fair scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html) where i can assign jobs to different pools in order to manage resources.

Which java equivalents exists for a non hadoop environment?